# Where to Cancel Coroutine Job's in View?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

i am using Coroutine in View's(Custom View) and these view's are added to a recycler view.

Most of the Calculation(complex and long) i am running on a coroutine `scopeIO` and updating view on `scopeMain`.

But when these view's are added to the Recycler View it work's perfectly but as i scroll fast then job's are running in the background even for the view's which are not visible anymore.

I am not sure where to cancel the Job. Most of the sample code i have seen are coroutine in activity where lifecycle is defined properly.

> i tried canceling the Job in `onDetachedFromWindow` but when
>   i scroll fast in recycler view it cancel's the job and while when view
>   is again attached to window it come's as empty view.

below is my coroutine declaration

```
 CustomView{
    .... 
    ....
    private val job = Job()
    private val scopeMain = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Main)
    private val scopeIO = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.IO)
    .... 
    ....
    }
```

As Due to above Many job's are alive and whole app become's laggy and at some point's crashes also.

P.S- Is it possible to have a single Job which can be used for rendering of whole recyclerView i.e same job for all child's(CustomView),i believe new Job() creation is causing the lag.

Demo Project i am working on :

- [CustomView](https://github.com/andor201995/RenderIt/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/show/singlecanvas/customview/slideView/SlideViewMultipleCanvas.kt#L77)
- [RecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/andor201995/RenderIt/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/show/singlecanvas/adapter/ViewPageAdapter.kt#L40)

Already referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58022726/7972699)

Comment: can you show us how you are using them?

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher u want code of the View and how i am using them then u can find it here https://github.com/andor201995/RenderIt/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/show/singlecanvas/customview/slideView/SlideViewMultipleCanvas.kt#L77

Comment: I think you need to learn more about coroutines because I see you are firing one one the Main thread and just doing a for loop in it.

Comment: can you point out where i have just started learning coroutine. @coroutineDispatcher

Comment: there where you have a `addView()` method inside the `for` - loop

Answer (score 5):

You can override '**onViewDetachedFromWindow()**' and call the cancel() on the corresponding job.

> onViewDetachedFromWindow  is called when a view becomes invisible & is
>   suited for your purpose.

From the android documentation:

> A view is recycled when a RecyclerView.LayoutManager decides that it
>   no longer needs to be attached to its parent RecyclerView. This can be
>   because it has fallen out of visibility or a set of cached views
>   represented by views still attached to the parent RecyclerView. If an
>   item view has large or expensive data bound to it such as large
>   bitmaps, this may be a good place to release those resources.

Link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH))

```
override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
    holder.yourView.cancelJob()
}
```

Similarly, when your view appears again:

```
onViewAttachedToWindow(holder:ViewHolder)
```

will be called. Here you have to restart the coroutine job.

```
holder.yourJob.start()
```

The reason for your problem is, you are cancelling the job, but when it comes to view again (it is not created again, it is being re-used i.e. the binding is done to an already created view), hence you need to start the job on your own.

Documentation from google says:

> Called when a view created by this adapter has been attached to a
>   window.
>   This can be used as a reasonable signal that the view is about to be
>   seen by the user. If the adapter previously freed any resources in
>   onViewDetachedFromWindow those resources should be restored here.

Link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH))

Now for your suggestion:

**OneJob for entire recycler**:

Your jobs are inside the view, so when the view gets created, the job executes. For you to be have one job, your job should exist outside the custom views. Your method should accept the view & the view should delegate the creation/initialisation of the view elements to this method.
This also means, you need to expose the view internals to this outside method. Doesn't sound very elegant to me. Also, if there are 7 items visible, your this "outside" method will be responsible for rendering all 7 elements, this will also affect performance when you scroll fast, as the method will be overwhelmed quite quickly for a fairly sized list.

Answer (score 1):

> You can override **'onViewRecycled'** in the RecyclerView.Adapter and cancel your 'Job' from this method

RecyclerView calls this method right before clearing ViewHolder's internal data and sending it to RecycledViewPool. This may be a good place to release any large resources or in your case stopping background work.

---

**Example**

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: CustomViewHolder) {
    holder.customView.cancelJob()
}
```

and you can start your background job in **'onBindViewHolder'** of the ViewHolder

Comment: Still he has to take care of the starting the job when the view becomes visible again.